# CDaoRecordset If a field Exists in MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc, dao

How do I check IF a Given Field Name already Exists in an Access database Table using VC++ DaoRecordSet. I tried Google and MSDN Documentation but could find anything useful.

I tried with the following Code:

```
BOOL IsFieldExixts(CDaoRecordset *rs, CString Fieldname)
{
   COleVariant OV;
   try
   {
      rs->GetFieldValue(FieldName,OV);
   }
   catch(CDaoException e)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE
}
```

But instead of raising a exception when not found, it displays a messagebox stating Item not found.

I need a C++ solution, all I can find on Google is vb solutions

Comment: This compiles? `catch` without `(exception-declaration)`!?

Comment: Are you sure that GetFieldValue is displaying the messagebox? Did you step through the code in a Debugger?

Comment: Yep, GetFieldValue is displaying the messagebox, it calls some function in wincore.cpp, and inside a CATCH_ALL(e) the messagebox is displayed

Comment: Nope, you did not step through the code in a debugger. You just assume that GetFieldValue is displaying the messagebox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetFieldValue` does not display any messagebox. Your `catch` block is not correct, you need to

```
catch(CDaoException *e) {
    e->Delete();
    return FALSE;
}
```

So in your program the exception is not handled in your code. Thus in an MFC top level function the default handler for exceptions is invoked and that one is displaying a messagebox.

BTW, to check if an entry exists in the recordset you can call `CDaoRecordset::IsEOF`.

Comment: @Wener Henze Now the catch block is being executed, but on the return FALSE statement it show a jet engine error message instead of returing false. On debugging, the code jumps to disassembly in visual studio after the return FALSE statement

Answer (score 0):

the recordset you can call ISEOF() method .

```
while(rs.IsEOF())
        {
            rs.Delete();
            rs.MovePrev();
        }
        rs.Close();//every time you should close the recordset connection
```